# Creating Timer to update Gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, timer

First, I am new to this so please bear with me.  I created a webpage that has a a form people can fill out and display the entries in a gridview linked to the sqltable.  The page works fine for one user, but if multiple user are using the website I want all users to see any changes to the sqltable automatically.  After reading multiple sites it sounds like I want to use a timer on the gridview but cannot find anything on how to do this.

If someone can point me in the right direction?

ASPX

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Workstation_Role.aspx.cs" Inherits="OnCallWeb.Dispatch_Policies.Workstation_Role" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            font-size: 14pt;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-size: 14pt;
            width: 56px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            font-size: 14pt;
            width: 311px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            font-size: 14pt;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            font-size: 14pt;
            margin-top: 9px;
        }
        .auto-style10 {
            font-size: 14pt;
            width: 214px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Name:</td>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="300px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnCallWebConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Personnel] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style10">Postion #: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" Width="130px">
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Training 7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Training 8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Training 9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Office</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    Roles:
             Roles:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" Width="772px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Status:</td>
                <td class="auto-style2" colspan="3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" Width="223px">
                        <asp:ListItem>At Desk</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Away From Desk</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;Dispatcher Covering:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="300px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnCallWebConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [PersonnelCovering] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style6" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Add To List" BackColor="#006600" ForeColor="White" />
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style6" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Update" BackColor="Yellow" />
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style6" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" Text="Delete" BackColor="Red" ForeColor="White" />
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style6" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" Text="Clear" BorderColor="Black" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7" colspan="4">
                    <div class="auto-style8">
                    </div>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnCallWebConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Position], [Roles], [Status], [DispatcherCovering], [ID] FROM [Dispatcher_Roles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="auto-style9" Width="1757px" EmptyDataText="No Records Found!">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" SortExpression="Position" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Roles" HeaderText="Roles" SortExpression="Roles" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DispatcherCovering" HeaderText="DispatcherCovering" SortExpression="DispatcherCovering" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Timers;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace OnCallWeb.Dispatch_Policies
{
    public partial class Workstation_Role : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnCallWebConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable dt;

        public void DataLoad()
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        public void ClearAllData()
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = DropDownList1.Items[0].ToString();
            DropDownList2.SelectedValue = DropDownList2.Items[0].ToString();
            DropDownList3.SelectedValue = DropDownList3.Items[0].ToString();
            DropDownList4.SelectedValue = DropDownList4.Items[0].ToString();
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            lblMessage.Text = "";
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            DropDownList3.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
            DropDownList4.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
            DropDownList2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != "" && DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "" && DropDownList3.SelectedValue != "")
            {
                using (con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Dispatcher_Roles (Name, Position, Roles, Status, DispatcherCovering) Values(@Name, @Position, @Roles, @Status, @DispatcherCovering)", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roles", TextBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList4.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispatcherCovering", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    DataLoad();
                    ClearAllData();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "***Fill In All Information***";
            }
        }
        protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != "" || DropDownList1.Text !="" || DropDownList2.Text !="")
                
            {
                using (con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Dispatcher_Roles Set Name=@Name, Position=@Position, Roles=@Roles, Status=@Status, DispatcherCovering=@DispatcherCovering where Name=@Name", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roles", TextBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList4.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispatcherCovering", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    DataLoad();
                    ClearAllData();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Fill In All All Fields";
            }
        }

        protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(con=new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Dispatcher_Roles where Name=@Name", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
                con.Close();
                DataLoad();
                ClearAllData();
            }
        }

        protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearAllData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a GridView.Databind to your save button, so at least users would then get a updated gv display on save. You CAN consider a timer, but this much suggests you want to place gridview in an update panel, since a timer DOES do a full page post-back (not really different then clicking on a button). This means that while a user is editing data, then you have post-backs, and that's going to interfere with general operations of that web page. Timer + update panel could work (put just gv + timer in update panel. 2nd option is ajax call, and 3rd option is SignalR as suggested below.

Comment: so, a timer might not work, since it depends on if the user edits or using the gv, or if you just need gv for display of data? If you have some type of gv editing involved here, then a timer not going to work. So, a timer might work, but only if post-backs are not a issue for you. SignalR is about the best, but it is a BIG set of moving parts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve real-time updates for multiple users viewing the gridview, you can consider using the SignalR library in ASP.NET. SignalR allows you to build real-time web applications by enabling server-side code to push content to connected clients instantly.

Here's how you can implement real-time updates for the gridview using SignalR:

Step 1: Install SignalR

- In Visual Studio, right-click on your project and select "Manage NuGet Packages."
- Search for "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" and install the package.

Step 2: Create a SignalR Hub

- Add a new class to your project and name it something like "GridUpdateHub.cs".
- Inherit the class from `Hub` provided by SignalR.
- Implement a method in the hub that will be called to send updates to the clients. For example, you can create a method named "UpdateGrid" to send the updated grid data to connected clients.

  using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

  public class GridUpdateHub : Hub
  {
  public void UpdateGrid(string data)
  {
  // Send the updated data to all connected clients
  Clients.All.updateGrid(data);
  }
  }

Step 3: Register the SignalR Hub

- Open the "Global.asax.cs" file in your project.
- Add the following code in the `Application_Start` method to register the SignalR hub:

  ```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Register the SignalR hub
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
  ```

  Step 4: Update the ASPX page

  - Add a reference to the SignalR JavaScript library in your ASPX page.
  - Add a JavaScript code to connect to the SignalR hub and handle the received updates. Place this code in the `<head>` section or at the end of the `<body>` section.

  $(function () {
            // Connect to the SignalR hub
            var hub = $.connection.gridUpdateHub;

            // Define a client-side method to handle received updates
            hub.client.updateGrid = function (data) {
                // Update the gridview or perform any other necessary actions with the updated data
                // For example, you can use JavaScript/jQuery to update the gridview dynamically
            };

            // Start the SignalR connection
            $.connection.hub.start();
        });

Step 5: Trigger updates from the server-side code

- In your server-side code (e.g., in the btnSave_Click or btnUpdate_Click methods), after saving or updating the data in the SQL table, you can send the updated data to connected clients using the SignalR hub.

  using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  // Save the data to the SQL table

  ```
    // Get the updated data from the SQL table
    string updatedData = GetUpdatedGridData(); // Implement this method to retrieve the updated data

    // Send the updated data to connected clients
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GridUpdateHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.All.updateGrid(updatedData);
  ```

  }

That's it! With this implementation, whenever a user saves or updates data, the SignalR hub will send the updated data to all connected clients, and the JavaScript code in the ASPX page will handle the received updates and update the gridview accordingly for all users in real-time

Happy coding!!